# how to create a dsn name for remote systems using mysql odbc connector

Tags: mysql, sql-server

i want access remote mysql form my system using (java/mssql) .

when i am start working on this i created linked server using mssql 2008 r2 at that time i am created one DSN name for mysql database using mysql odbc connector, i used

> localhost

as a server name but actually i need to created on DSN for remote server instead of localhost i want to use

> 192.168.1.120

at that i am getting errors like

> connection failed hy000 mysql odbc 5.1 driver can't connect to mysql
>   server

please help me , i am working on last 7 days

thanks in advance

Comment: Unfortunately your question is very unclear, what does MSSQL have to do with this? You need to explain a) where the MySQL server is, b) where the application that will connect to MySQL is, c) exactly how you are creating the DSN and d) exactly when the error occurs.

Comment: While you can use ODBC in Java as described here http://spatial.wordpress.com/2006/03/18/accesing-odbc-data-source-from-java-program/ if you are going to be doing Java programming look at JDBC.

Comment: i want updations of local mssql need to updated in remote mysql database...
a)it is another system beside me(connected in LAN)
b)linked server of mssql is connecting to mysql(for that linked server creation also i need to create DSN for remote mysql)
c)i installed mysql odbc driver 5.1 using this i am trying to create a DSN
d)after entering server name ,username and pwd when i am clicking TEST button at that time i am getting this error "connection failed hy000 mysql odbc 5.1 driver can't connect to mysql server on '192.168.1.120'"

Comment: For now, I would forget everything except the basic connection issue. Can you connect to MySQL using MySQL client tools like mysql.exe or whatever? Are you sure that the user account you're using has the correct permissions to connect? Are you sure that the network connection is OK? Etc. and you may get a better response on the dba or serverfault site for connectivity issues related to security or the network.